# Multipeer connectivity framework iOS 10 issue

Tags: objective-c, iphone, bluetooth, ios10, multipeer-connectivity

I am having an hard time with Multipeer connectivity framework.

I am using multipeer connectivity frame to send data between 2 iPads using Wifi/Adhoc Wifi/Bluetooth. It is all working fine in iOS 9.x. But with iOS 10 all scenarios except sending data via Bluetooth is working.

In iOS 10 with Bluetooth, peer is discovered and the delegate method for that is invoked

```
- (void)        browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser
                            foundPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID
            withDiscoveryInfo:(nullable NSDictionary<NSString *, NSString *> *)info
```

But after issue with a connection request using `invitePeer:toSession:withContext:timeout` , after 10-20 Sec

`- (void)browser:(MCNearbyServiceBrowser *)browser lostPeer:(MCPeerID *)peerID` is getting called.

I checked the apple documentation and it says no API changes in the Framework for iOS 10 (https://developer.apple.com/reference/multipeerconnectivity?changes=latest_major&language=objc, https://developer.apple.com/library/content/releasenotes/General/iOS10APIDiffs/).
I could see same bluetooth connectivity issue in apps that are in AppStore.

I tried with sample code provided by apple(https://developer.apple.com/library/content/samplecode/MultipeerGroupChat/Introduction/Intro.html), could find the same issue.

Any help on this is greatly is appreciated.